# Entending my JavaScript regular expression for a comma separated list of tags to allow whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written a JavaScript regular expression to validate a comma separated list of tags.
A tag can contain characters A-Z, a-z, 0-9, space, hyphen and apostrophe, and is 3-50 characters long.

Here is what I have:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\- ']{3,50}(,[a-zA-Z0-9\- ']{3,50})*$
```

I want to extend this to allow the user to provide no tags at all. However, if I put a question mark after the first tag section of the regex, it will allow things like `,tag`

How would I make it allow whitespace or the above? (I'd say allow it to be blank or the above, but as I'm going to trim the entry, I'll be lenient and say whitespace is OK)

Comment: Not sure if this is a good approach. How can you possibly say to the user that tag x is too long or tag y has invalid characters

Comment: Do you mean space characters or any sort of whitespace? If the latter, you do mean just horizontal whitespace, right, not vertical? What is the data source?  Is it ASCII?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a try:

```
^([-a-zA-Z0-9 ']{3,50},)*([-a-zA-Z0-9 ']{3,50})?$
```

Comment: Uncanny. I went for the obvious but this solution is smarter.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(\s*|[a-zA-Z0-9\- ']{3,50}(,[a-zA-Z0-9\- ']{3,50})*)$
```